# LGHT warning 1076 :ICE 60

Tags: wix, windows-installer

How do I get rid of light warning 1076 : with ICE 60. Would my installer be instable in any form later if i don't get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

ICE60 indicates a binary (that is, a file in PE format) which contains a version resource, but not marked for a particular language. Use the warning message to determine which binary **light** is complaining about, and mark that binary with the appropriate language (recompile from source, or use a resource editor), then re-package the install.

File versions are expressed as *major.minor.build.iteration* , for example 2.0.50727.42 (which is the version of the first .NET 2.0 Framework release). MSI file search has a [non-obvious quirk](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/check_the_version_number.htm) when comparing versions: the version must match not only all four numbers *but also the language*. To make the search language-neutral, look for a version *just less than* the version you actually want (e.g. MinVersion="2.0.50727.41" instead of .42).

A binary whose language is not indicated at all therefore cannot possibly be an exact match to a given version number. That's why **light** gives you this warning.

If language is not a problem, then yes, your installer should be installable even with this warning.